# How to produce only dvi file with latex on Mac

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, mactex

Recently, I switched to MacTex, I somehow get used to run the following sequence on a Windows command terminal:

1. latex  *.tex   ->generate only dvi file
2. bibtex *.aux
3. latex  *.tex
4. dvipdfm *.dvi  ->generate the final pdf file

However, now when I launch a terminal on Mac(Yosemite), running latex *.tex
would directly generate the final pdf without the intermediate steps, seems to me "latex" is hardlinked to a combination of commands? Is there a way to follow the same steps as I used to ?

Comment: `latex foo.tex` should generate `foo.dvi`, not `foo.pdf`.

Answer (score 5):

The `latex`program is actually `pdflatex` running in `dvi` mode. According to `latex --help`, the output format can be set with

```
-output-format=FORMAT   use FORMAT for job output; FORMAT is `dvi' or `pdf'
```

So you can try to force the `dvi` output by compiling with:

```
latex file.tex -output-format=dvi
```

What you have though actually does the same, if `latex` is giving you a `pdf` file, and if that's what you want, you can just run `latex,bibtex,latex,latex` and it will give you the right pdf file, so unless you specifically want the `dvi` file there's no any reason to produce it.

Comment: this works, indeed pdf directly generated is much larger than the other... But is there a way to default it ?

Comment: @lorniper That I don't know, sorry. There's probably some unix trick to do so. If you don't get an answer here you could try to ask on stackoverflow if there's any way to default terminal commands